# "Один" или "раз"?

Tags: этимология, числительные

Когда уместно и правильно говорить "раз", а когда "один? И как получилось, что для одного числительного образовалось два слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Раз" - вообще-то не числительное. Единственный случай, когда оно выступает в роли числительного - счет, обычно устный. *"Раз, два, три...", "Раз, два и готово"*

В остальных случаях *раз* либо существительное ("два раза"), либо это вообще совершенно другое слово (омоним), наречие или союз.

Спутать трудно.

Answer (score 2):

Дополнение о происхождении слов РАЗ и ОДИН.

**РАЗ** «один», «однажды», «однократное действие». Общеслав. Современная его форма развилась из праслав. «резьба, резанье» (ср. современное *резь* «острая режущая боль»), вследствие перегласовки (как лезть — лазить).

Что касается слова ОДИН, то праслав. *edinъ было сложным словом, образованным из* ed-, выступавшим в роли усилительно-ограничительной частицы «именно, только» (см. едва), 
и *nъ, (*ino) «один». В старославянском языке слово единъ означало «только один».

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с тем, что РАЗ - не числительное.
Как вам такой пример из цепочки аналогий:
Это, как представляется, существительное, постепенно из области счёта количества действий перешедшее в счёт количества предметов.
Аналогия:
Одна тысяча, две тысячи, три тысячи..., а можно и так
Тысяча, две тысячи, три тысячи...
Похоже?  ОДНА ТЫСЯЧА мы сократили до ТЫСЯЧА.
Но если считать действия, то можно так:
Один раз, два раза, три раза....
Раз, два раза, три раза
ОДИН РАЗ мы сократили до РАЗ
Получаются необязательные слова, при счете действий правильно и так, и так:
Один[раз], два[раза], три[раза]...
[Один]раз, два[раза], три[раза]...
Я думаю, постепенно в разговорной речи ОДИН и РАЗ стали восприниматься как синонимы, поэтому и при счете предметов начали употреблять это существительное.
Ну как-то так.

Answer (score -1):

Славянское РАЗ - единица МЕРЫ, тоже самое скандинавское ОДИН или ОРТ - математический вектор единичной длины в котором можно заключить и МЕРУ ПРОСТРАНСТВА (раз-мер), и МЕРУ ЭНЕРГИИ (раз-ход), и МЕРУ ВРЕМЕНИ (раз-свет). ТРИ - ЕДИН(ОДИН)-ство, МА-ТРЁ-шка, МА-ТРИ-АРХ-ат, МА-ТРИ-ца... Возможно, слово РАЗ связано с дренеарийским словом РА (солнце) - корни которого остались в русских словах РА-дуга, по-РА, у-РА и т.д. 
Прим. пусть вас не смущает написание слов раЗход и раЗсвет, до реформ начала 20-го века они писались именно так...

Comment: >Славянское РАЗ - единица МЕРЫ
меры чего?

Остальное вообще dcr трудноперевариваемое. "Смешались в кучу, кони люди". Вплоть до египтян...

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам версия:

Славяне словом раз называли первый луч рассветного солнца. Отсюда в устном счёте всё, что первое, то-раз!