# Какое происхождение слова "раз"?

Tags: этимология

Какое происхождение слова  "раз"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7

Answer (score 2):

Шанский Н. М. утверждает, что

> Раз - общеславянское. Производное от разить (см.). Раз исходно «удар».
>   Ср. отразить, образ.

Фасмер М.:

I. Приставка; рас- — перед глухими согласными. Цслав. форма вместо исконнорусск. роз-, рос-. См. роз-

> II, род. п. -а, сюда же о́браз, укр., блр. раз, сербохорв. рȃз
>   «лопатка для отмеривания зерна», «отвал плуга», словен. rȃz «гребок
>   для отмеривания зерна», чеш. ráz «удар, отпечаток, чеканка, тип,
>   характер», слвц. rаz «характер, удар», польск. rаz «раз», в.-луж.,
>   н.-луж. rаz «раз» Первонач. *razъ «удар», связанное чередованием
>   гласных с ре́зать (см.). Родственно лит. rúоžаs «полоса, черта»,
>   rė́žti «резать, делать черту», лтш. ruôzа «возвышенность, бугор;
>   полоса, луг, ряд», греч. ῥώξ м., ж. «трещина».

Происхождение слова раз в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Успенского Л. В.:

> Раз. Того же корня, что «резать», в котором произошла перегласовка,
>   смена гласных звуков, как в «вал» — «волна» (см.). Наверное, вначале
>   слово значило «один удар»: говорим же мы «разить мечом».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%80/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это от слова "**Рас**" в значении "**солнце**". Поскольку солнце *одно на небе*, значит "раз" - это один.

Что касается "**разить мечом**", то оно вписывается в данное объяснение, если понимать его как "**убить врага с одного удара**" - "раз и готово" - ра́зить - "рази́ть".

Также по В. Далю "*слитный предлог*" "**раз**" имеет формы "рас, рос, разо", что подтверждает преобразование **"рас" - "раз"**. Например: развить, растить, разогреть, распрекрасный. Если присмотреться, то в этих словах значение, передаваемое "слитным предлогом", можно объяснить как "освещаемый солнцем":
развить - солнце способствует развитию;
растить - растения растут под влиянием солнца;
разогреть - солнце греет;
распрекрасный - высшая степень; солнце - оно выше всего.

Также фамилия Степана **Разина** содержит в себе понятие "**раз**" - то есть "первый", а также с подтекстом "солнце" и "высший".

Сюда вроде бы не вписывается слово "**разный**", однако это связано с *движением солнца по небу*: оно восходит на востоке и садится на западе; оно днём есть, а ночью его нет; значит солнце хоть и одно, но ведёт себя "разно".
Смотрим у Вл. Даля слово [разный](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9): "РАЗНЫЙ... не один... не один и тот же... сам по себе" - объясняется от понятия "один".

Противоположное "**одинаковый**" - тоже связано с понятием "один".